# How do I include a .pl file in Prolog?

Tags: file, include, prolog

I'd like to include code from another source file. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your file is called `foo.pl`, you can include it using

```
:- [foo].
```

or, equivalently and a bit more explicit

```
:- consult(foo).
```

or, if you're worried it may be loaded several times in a larger app

```
:- ensure_loaded(foo).
```

or, if you're using [full-blown modules](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=use_module%2F2)

```
:- use_module(foo).
```

though the exact name of the last predicate differs between Prolog versions.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to include the file literally - similar to #include, use
:- include('file.pl').

Most of the time it is preferable to structure your program using
modules, though.