# Include prolog file in another file, but by calling it in specific order?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have two files, file1 and file2 with prolog extension, in file1 in some cases file2 is appended with new predicates, so I have to consult file2 in some specific area in file1,
I did check this question
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097451/how-do-i-include-a-pl-file-in-prolog), but I want a different behavior, what I want to do is :

in file1

```
consult_File:-
                  consult('C:/Users/../Prolog/file2.pl').
```

and under specific condition, I can call consult_File, but unfortunately if I call consult_File within other codes in File1, it doesn't work, and if you call it explicitly from the command, it works.
I appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: `consult_File` should work. Do you know how to debug your code?

Comment: I did trace the code,but it didn't consult the file,
Does it make difference if trace or debug ?

Comment: yes, but trace is ok. Can't you understand why consult_File isn't called? If you do unconditionally, with a directive (i.e. `:- consult('C:/Users/../Prolog/file2.pl').` ) it's ok?

Comment: I did discover the error, and I would like to share it with you, it's supposed to work fine, but I have in my file:
`code`
start:-
      read_from_file,consult_new_File.

`code`
and in read from file, there is a condition which checks if each character isn't equal to end of file, and once it's reached to end of file, it fails and I didn't handle else of if statement, that's why each time, it fails, the code inside read_from_file is done correctly but fails once reached to end of file,
so I handle it by putting true in else of if statement

Thanks,

Comment: By all means: Use SWI's module system instead! I cannot see a good reason why you want what you describe. If you structure your code cleanly you will benefit using SWI's `make` and cross-referencer!